# Отправка информации с локальной html страницы в Excel файл с помощью python

Tags: python, html, excel

Существует локальная html страница (только на компе) с некоторой формой для заполнения. Хочу чтобы результаты заполнения этой формы отправлялись в файл Excel. В общем то хочу сделать парсер, только не очень понимаю как его делать для локальной страниц, какими библиотеками пользоваться. Beautiful soup вроде бы для онлайн а. Может кто посоветует куда копать, где подсмотреть или почитать.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` работает и без онлайн а

Comment: Если эта страница "только на компе" и данные с нее куда-то отправляются, зачем делать парсер, если данные можно просто забрать оттуда, куда они отправляются?

Comment: По проекту будет несколько отдельных html страниц, из них заполненная информация будет сводится в один Excel файл.